# When I enter the terminal command "$ node fileName.js" the concole throws out a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio, syntax

## My Env.:

- React v17.0.2
- node v16.6.1
- npm v7.20.3
- VS Code
- Windows 10

### The Problem:

I am currently working on a cooking recipe app for a friend's website. My issue is that whenever I enter "node fileName.js" into my terminal to run and check the console.log's and other outputs for my code, the terminal always trows out the following error:

### Error Message:

```
[Running] node "c:\Users\...\Desktop\...\src\App.js"
file:///c:/Users/.../Desktop/.../src/App.js:6
    <div className="App">
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:146:18)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:67:21)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.404 seconds
```

### TLDR

My code itself works fine on http://localhost:3000/, but I was wondering if anybody has an idea how to fix a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" issue in a React project, since it gets in the way of testing/debugging code.

##### PS: This is the content of the whole file

```
import './App.css';
import recipeCards from './components/functional/recipe-cards';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>This is a header</p>
        <nav>
          <p>This is a nav</p>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <main>
        <p>This is the main content</p>
        
        <section>
          <p>This is a section</p>

              {recipeCards}

        </section>

      </main>

      <footer>
        <p>This is the footer</p>
      </footer>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: nodejs doesn't understand reactjs - it runs javascript

Comment: @Bravo , Is there a way how I can run/debug my React code in the VS Code terminal then? I understand that I can just type in "npm start" and see the rendered code in http://localhost:3000/, but what about checking console.log() and other functions/methods when developing and testing code?

Comment: @Bravo . I have heard some people mentioning something like Babel when talking about JSX or is that irrelevant?

Comment: console.log in the browser, or on the server code? in the browser, use the browser developer tools, on the server code, well console.log will output to the vs code terminal where you run `npm start`

Comment: @Bravo , thank you for the clarification. I was hoping that there would be a "lazy" way hoe to do that from the VS code terminal without using Chrome Dev tools or something like that. But least now I don`t have to ponder about these things. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect there is some way, but I don't use Chrome .... ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by importing React at the top of the file:

```js
import React from 'react';
```